# Calculating tax

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to keep a running subtotal of items order in a program I am making in Visual Studio 2012.  I have that part working.  However when I try to code to do taxes and then a new total, something isn't working.  Here is what I have so far.  Sorry I would have a copy of all of the code but its on a different machine that is having issues getting connected to the internet.
Under the button when clicked (three variables already declared: subtotal, tax, total; everytime a user orders something new, subtotal is updated.)

```
tax = 0.02 * subtotal
total = subtotal + tax
...
```

Right now it just gives me the subtotal, and tax as 0 and total as the same as subtotal.
I have the variables declared as integers. 
Why isn't the tax working?
I am using Visual Basic...

Comment: What language are you using? "Visual Studio 2012" isn't a programming language. You need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: An *integer* cannot hold fractional numbers. VB.Net will allow the assignment of a double (0.02) but applies rounding. Use a more appropriate type such as *Decimal*.

Comment: okay thought that might be the problem...I am still kind of new at this...

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are declared as `int` or `Integer` (your code looks like VB.NET) then floating-point results will get rounded down to the nearest integer value - integers can only hold integer values, not fractions. You need to use either `Single` or `Double` to store fractional values. Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) of data types to understand the differences.

If you're performing financial calculations, use the `Decimal` data type - `Single` and `Double` are for scientific calculations but they are not suited to represent exact fractional values at arbitrary precision. For financial calculations, where you need exact fractional values at a set precision, `Decimal` is the right type.

We don't know the value of `subtotal` but if it's small, multiplying it by `0.02` will turn it to `0`.

You should use the debugger to step through your program and see the state if variables.

Comment: Look at the formatting options in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @SaraSelf Updated the answer for financial calculations.